# tkinter press button to export predictive result

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

How can I save the predictive result as a txt or csv?

I have got the code below and it did export but not the predictive result..

How can I rewrite the code?

Thanks in advance!

Below code is about a regression model testing on the prediction and trying to figure out predictive number via tkinter:

```html
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import tkinter as tk 

candidates = {'gmat': [780,750,690,710,780,730,690,720,740,690,610,690,710,680,770,610,580,650,540,590,620,600,550,550,570,670,660,580,650,760,640,620,660,660,680,650,670,580,590,790],
              'gpa': [4,3.9,3.3,3.7,3.9,3.7,2.3,3.3,3.3,1.7,2.7,3.7,3.7,3.3,3.3,3,2.7,3.7,2.7,2.3,3.3,2,2.3,2.7,3,3.3,3.7,2.3,3.7,3.3,3,2.7,4,3.3,3.3,2.3,2.7,3.3,1.7,3.7],
              'admitted': [2,2,1,2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,2,2,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2]
              }

df = pd.DataFrame(candidates,columns= ['gmat', 'gpa','admitted'])
#print (df)

X = df[['gmat', 'gpa']]
y = df['admitted']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)a
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# tkinter GUI
root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 350)
canvas1.pack()

# GMAT
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='            GMAT:')
canvas1.create_window(100, 100, window=label1)

entry1 = tk.Entry (root)
canvas1.create_window(270, 100, window=entry1)

# GPA
label2 = tk.Label(root, text='GPA:     ')
canvas1.create_window(120, 120, window=label2)

entry2 = tk.Entry (root)
canvas1.create_window(270, 120, window=entry2)

def values(): 
    global gmat
    gmat = float(entry1.get()) 

    global gpa
    gpa = float(entry2.get()) 

    Prediction_result  = ('  Predicted Result: ', clf.predict([[gmat,gpa]]))
    label_Prediction = tk.Label(root, text= Prediction_result, bg='sky blue')
    canvas1.create_window(270, 280, window=label_Prediction)

button1 = tk.Button (root, text='      Predict      ',command=values, bg='green', fg='white', font=11)
canvas1.create_window(270, 220, window=button1)

print(button1, file = open(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\Result.txt', 'w'))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you get the correct values shown in the Label window

this

```py
print(button1, file = open(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\Result.txt', 'w'))
```

prints the internal representation of `button1` to your file, something like `.!button`

Hence , remove that line and put

```py
print(Prediction_result[1], file = open(r'C:\Users\Lawrence\Desktop\Result.txt', 'w'))
```

as the last line in function `values`